Probability mass function of number of boxes with exactly one ball
I am having some troubles solving this problem:
Suppose 10 balls are placed randomly in 4 boxes and each ball will be placed independently in box $i$ with probability $p_i,$ with $p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4=1.$ Let $X$ be the random variable that counts the number of boxes left with exactly one ball. Find the probability mass function of $X.$
The support of $X$ is the set $\{0,1,2,3\}.$ So we have to compute $P(X = j)$ for each $j$ in the support of $X.$
So, for example, to calculate $P(X = 1)$ we need to consider the event where only box 1 has exactly 1 ball; similar with box 2, 3 and 4, and the sum of all previous probabilities gives $P(X = 1).$ Then, to compute probability of the event where only box 1 has exactly 1 ball is the sum of all non negative integer solutions of the equation $x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 9$ of the terms $\binom{10}{1, x_2, x_3, x_4}p_{1}p_{2}^{x_2}p_{3}^{x_3}p_{4}^{x_4}$
To compute $P(X = 2)$ we need to sum terms like $\sum\binom{10}{1, 1, x_3, x_4}p_{1}p_{2}p_{3}^{x_3}p_{4}^{x_4},$ where each sum is over all non negative integer solutions of the equation $x_3 + x_4 = 8.$ And there are ${4\choose 2}$ terms very similar like the previous, where 2 of the boxes have exactly 1 ball each one, are selected among 4.
I am not sure about my reasoning. I suspect there is a better (and easier) way to solve this. ¿How could be solved this problem?
Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

With numbers this small, I don't think that you can do better than the brute force approach indicated in your answer.  If (instead), there were $~100~$ balls and $~20~$ boxes, then I would suggest $~p(k) = \displaystyle \binom{100}{k} \times g(k),~$ where $~g(k)~$ is determined (perhaps) by using inclusion-exclusion on the $~(20-k)~$ boxes and $~(100-k)~$ balls.  That approach seems like overkill here.


Find the probability mass function of .

This problem can simply let $X_i$  be an indicator variable that equals 1 if box  i  contains exactly one ball, and 0 otherwise. Then the total number of boxes that contain exactly one ball,  X , is the sum of these indicator variables:
$
X = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4
$
In addition, each ball is placed into one of the four boxes independently, with probabilities  $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ , respectively, then the probability that exactly one ball goes into box  i, and the other 9 balls do not, is given by:
$
P(\text{exactly one ball in box } i) = 10 p_i (1 - p_i)^9
$
So that the probability mass function for  X  is given by:
$P(X = j) = \sum_{\text{all possible ways}} P(\text{configuration that leads to } X = j)$
To compute (=2), the probability that both boxes contain exactly one ball and the other two boxes contain either no balls or more than one ball for any particular pair of boxes,
$P(X = 2) = \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq 4} \left( P(\text{1 ball in box } i) \times P(\text{1 ball in box } j) \times P(\text{no or more than 1 ball in boxes } k \text{ and } l) \right)
$
, where
$
P(\text{1 ball in box } i) = 10 p_i (1 - p_i)^9,
$
$
P(\text{1 ball in box } j) = 10 p_j (1 - p_j)^9,
$
$
P(\text{no or more than 1 ball in box } k) = 1 - 10 p_k (1 - p_k)^9 - (1 - p_k)^{10},
$
$ 
P(\text{no or more than 1 ball in box } l) = 1 - 10 p_l (1 - p_l)^9 - (1 - p_l)^{10}
$
